# Creating a bot connection via Azure ARM Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-resource-manager

So, I've being trying to use the Azure Rest API to create some resources. More specifically I'm trying to create a bot connection using Insomnia. The request and the response are like so:

[image: Insomnia screenshot]

I'm using PUT method (as you can see) and the URL (with sensitive data redacted) is as follows:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/bot-poc-myweb/Connections/mywebbot?api-version=2018-07-12`

The error says the connection resource wasn't found. Well.. No suprise here, since I'm kinda trying to create it. Anyone knows what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Request URL:**

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/<bot_name>/Connections/<conn_name>?api-version=2018-07-12
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "location": "global",
    "properties": {
        "scopes": "<scopes>",
        "serviceProviderId": "30dd229c-58e3-4a48-bdfd-91ec48eb906c",
        "clientId": "<client id>",
        "clientSecret": "<secret>",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "key": "clientId",
                "value": "<client id>"
            },
            {
                "key": "clientSecret",
                "value": "<secret>"
            },
            {
                "key": "tokenExchangeUrl",
                "value": "<token exchange URL>"
            },
            {
                "key": "tenantId",
                "value": "<tenant id>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]